# How to check number of parked cores in command line (win, lin) via ssh

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, cmd.exe, cygwin

I'm wondering how to check number of **parked cores** via CMD on Windows remotely, via ssh. I'm also using cygwin there, so bash scrips would also help. I tried to look for answers but it usualy directs me to windows GUI resource monitor or 3rd party software which I can't install on customer's machine. Any ideas? :) Thx.

Comment: what do you mean with `parked cores` ?

Comment: In modern CPU's operating systems are able to park cores, meaning they certain cores might be dicamically turned on/off. Parked cores are visible in GUI of windows resource monitor, when you hoover on core that is parked, you'll see it's state. Im looking for a way to get this information via CMD line, but no luck so far.

Comment: all the info about CPU are reported in `/proc/cpuinfo` If you know how Linux detect the parked code, it can be added to the Cygwin detection in  https://cygwin.com/git/?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=winsup/cygwin/fhandler_proc.cc;h=501c157daae5ca0e61dafd9c260b3c26488d765f;hb=HEAD

Comment: /proc/cpuinfo does not report which CPU is parked, I checked that long before asking for help here ;)

Comment: I know that does not report. I was saying that if you know how the information can be retrieved it can be added to `/proc/cpuinfo`. The guy that is following that portion of the code is usually responsive. https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin-patches/2021q1/011152.html